# Is writing to `gl_Position` in Vertex Shader necessary when there is a Geometry Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

Suppose I have a geometry shader that computes its output `gl_Position` from some inputs other than `gl_in[].gl_Position`. If the previous pipelines stages (vertex and tessellation) do not write to their `out gl_Position`, does the action of the entire pipeline still remain well-defined?

Or put it other way, does the value of `gl_Position` has any effect on the functioning of the GL before the completion of the Geometry shader? If not, it would mean I can simply use it as an extra slot for passing data without any special spatial interpretation between stages, right?

(The question assumes OpenGL 4.5 forward profile.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gl_Position` only needs to be written by the final [Vertex Processing](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Processing) stage (VS, tessellation, and GS) in the rendering pipeline. So if you have an active GS, the VS that connects to it need not write to `gl_Position` at all. Or it can put any arbitrary `vec4` data in it.

Do note that `gl_Position` does still need to be written by whatever the final vertex processing stage is. Assuming you want rasterization, of course. And no, that's not being flippant; you could be doing transform feedback.

> If not, it would mean I can simply use it as an extra slot for passing data without any special spatial interpretation between stages, right?

If there's a GS, then *none* of the outputs from the previous shader stages will have "any special spatial interpretation". `gl_Position` isn't special in this regard.

Interpolation is a function of the Rasterizer, which happens after vertex processing. Indeed, in GLSL 4.30+, the interpolation qualifiers on the fragment shader inputs are the *only* ones that matter. They're not even used for interface matching anymore.

Comment: Great answer. I'm just trying to find the place in the spec that confirms this. So far my best candidates are: "Clip coordinates for a vertex result from shader execution, which yields a vertex coordinate gl_Position." from 'gl4.4core section 13.6' and the equivalent "Clip coordinates for a vertex result from vertex or, if active, geometry shader execution, which yields a vertex coordinate gl_Position." from 'gl3.3core section 2.13'. Am I in the right place?